# CrossDomain POST issue in Android Emulator using PhoneGap

Tags: android-emulator, cordova, cross-domain

I'm building a hybrid mobile application (PhoneGap+JQM).  While testing in the Android emulator, I'm observing what must be a cross-domain POST issue against a SOAP web service.  I can do a GET for the WSDL (thus proving I can indeed reach the domain in question).  But if I change my request to a POST with a SOAP payload, I get an error.  (LogCat shows "Internal Server Error" in the error callback function.)

I've seen posts and documentation on how cross-domain POSTs aren't prohibited using PhoneGap, but in my emulator it's not being allowed.  Any thoughts on what I may be missing?

Comment: well, embarrasingly enough, it was indeed hitting the server.  (you would think an error like 'internal server error' would clue one in :-)  my jquery error callback simply wasn't showing me the fault details.  so i put a sniffer on it to verify, and that's how i found out that the traffic was going through.  and for what it's worth, i was missing the SOAPAction HTTP header, thus the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above.  Hopefully others will learn from this if they get unknown web-service errors.  (always use SoapUI to verify correct content, and use a sniffer to double-check your own POST)